# Installed Linux (Apricity OS) regret it and now I want Windows back

Tags: linux, windows, boot, grub

I’ve installed Linux (Apricity OS) and now I regret and want Windows 10 back. I created a bootable USB disk with Windows ISO and when I try to boot to it GRUB loads and let me choose to boot only to Apricity OS. What can I do?

Comment: Do you literally have a window `.ISO` *file* on the USB stick, or did you copy the *contents* of the `.ISO` file to the USB stick? (You can't boot from an ISO *file*)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the status of your computer so it's difficult to give an exact answer, but:

- **Check the boot order of your computer in BIOS, and make sure USB is in the top of the list (the first one)**

Answer (score 1):

If you told the Apricity OS installer to wipe your hard drive entirely, then yes, reinstalling Windows is the only way to get Windows back.

However, if you configured the Apricity installer to do a dual-boot with Windows and the only issue is that Grub isn't showing an option to boot back into Windows, you can try opening Terminal in Apricity OS and running

```
su -c 'os-prober && grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg'
```

That will force GRUB to look for new operating systems and put them in the boot menu. If you did have the Apricity installer erase your hard drive and just want to boot from a USB drive, you’ll have to select your Windows USB drive in your BIOS's boot menu the same way you did when you were booting from the Apricity OS live USB.

GRUB doesn’t normally support booting from live USBs, although it is possible—though rare—to configure it to do so. You can access your BIOS’s boot menu by pressing one of the function keys, often <kbd>F12</kbd>.

Might I ask what you disliked about Apricity OS?

Comment: thanks for your answer!
I really liked the OS but linux is too complicated too me....

Comment: I didn't help....